# How to change chat text in bukkit after being posted?

Tags: java, chat, minecraft, bukkit

Ok, so I want to animate some text with prefix [anim]something, so the color changes. So after the player sends the text, I can get text in the plugin without posting it yet. So then I can do something with text and then I post it. But I don't think I can animate it this way.

Any suggestions on how to update only one line of chat without having to store and re-post whole chat text?

Thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately, you'll have to animate the whole chat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot change chat messages after being sent.

So the only way to do it would be exactly what you want to avoid, re-posting the whole chat.

Comment: An example on how to do it would be useful as an answer.

Comment: Yeah. I checked your answer as the correct one, but could you please give me an example on how I'd be goin' if I wanted to re-post all of the chat again... Thanks!